# Statement about local extrema

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to answer this question:

[image]

I know that B) and C) are obviously not true. A) is also not true since the statement should be "If $x_0$ is a local extremum then $f'(x_0)=0$". However, I'm not sure if the correct answer is D) or E) because we haven't been told if $x_0 \in (a,b)$. I think it would be D) because whether $f$ is differentiable or not at $x_0$ we know that if $f'(x_0)\neq0$ then $x_0$ cannot be a local extremum. But I'm not sure if I'm right because I also know that the contrapositive for Fermat's theorem for stationary points is "If $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $f'(x_0) \neq0$ then $x_0$ is not a local extremum" which is not the same as D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $A$ is wrong. $f(x)=x^3$ doesn't have a local extrema at $x=0$.

$D$ is the correct answer. $D$ says the same thing as Fermat's Theorem for Stationary Points.